# How to support dynamic type hinting with metaprogramming in PyCharm?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pycharm, metaprogramming, type-hinting

In PyCharm, the type hinting can support the standard library `dataclass` properly. However, when I use the same implement with mydataclass, the PyCharm can not support that:

```
from dataclasses import dataclass
from typing import Tuple, Dict, TypeVar

_C = TypeVar('_C', bound=type)


class TestORM(type):
    def __new__(cls, clsname: str, bases: Tuple, clsdict: Dict):
        param = ""
        for key, key_type in clsdict.get('__annotations__', {}).items():
            param += f", {key}: {key_type.__name__} = {clsdict.get(key)}"
        clsdict['__init__'] = make_init(param)
        return super().__new__(cls, clsname, bases, clsdict)


@dataclass
class Test:
    a: int = 0


def mydataclass(cls: _C) -> _C:
    param = ""
    for key, key_type in cls.__annotations__.items():
        param += f", {key}: {key_type.__name__} = {getattr(cls, key)}"
    setattr(cls, "__init__", make_init(param))
    return cls


def make_init(param:str):
    locals = {}
    txt = f'def __init__(self{param}):\n   pass'
    exec(txt, None, locals)
    return locals['__init__']


@mydataclass
class MyTest:
    a: int = 0

class MyORMTest(metaclass=TestORM):
    a: int = 0

if __name__ == '__main__':
    Test(a='a')
    MyTest(a='a')
    MyORMTest(a='a')
```

[image: The actual result in PyCharm]

How would I do to make the PyCharm type hinting work?

To sum up, I just want to know how does PyCharm work with custom class with `dataclass` without any stub files which are with regard to the custom class. And when I use the same implement as `dataclass` with `exec` to make my `__init__` function dynamic, I still can not get the proper type hinting.

Does the PyCharm do some specific parse or check for the specific library?

Comment: Weird code. No IDE can support this type inference with eval in between. Python has metaclasses and other mechanisms if you really need to do something like that.

Comment: It is normal code and the standard library `dataclass` is using this way.

Comment: True - `exec` is used in that standard lib module. Maybe GvR weakened his control over codebase...

Comment: I do not think so, GvR himself provided invaluable input during the development of this [PEP 557](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0557) -- `Data Classes` and code. And I think it is a normal way to achieve an ORM-like Object.

Comment: Ok. I see your point: "One main design goal of Data Classes is to support static type checkers." - from the PEP 557. However, you are creating your own dataclass implementation and hope PyCharm will happily understand that. I do not believe it ever happen with static type checkers. I rather believe Python will develop proper type mechanisms for such kind of tricks to avoid exec/eval.

Comment: Some metaprogramming libraries/decorators has special support in PyCharm, e.g. [dataclasses](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-27398) and [`attrs`](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-26354)

Answer (score 2):

Python is a dynamic language. That means an object can be anything, and can be transformed at run time.

Certain features, like type-hinting, work by static analysis - and Pycharm toolchain did incorporate some type-hinting fetures that can also inspect  Python's own dataclasses by static analysis. Static annalysis means: it is not doe with the "live" data - it is done by looking at the code, and inspecting it over a subset of rules that are learned separate from the language.

In short: there is no POSSIBLE mechanism the tools used by Pycharm can infer type hinting for arbitrary dynamic code. 
It is just not possible.

If you are creating an extensive framework for which you'd absolutely like to have static type hinting within the IDE, you will have to fetc the source of the tools used by the IDE itself (I am not sure if dataclasses' type hinting is done by `mypy` itself or some other tool), and extend one of the tools - or create one of your own, that will be able to introspect the types declared in your framework, in the usual way you do declare then.

Otherwise it just won't happen.

Comment: Yes, I know that. But I mean that the PyCharm can hint the proper type without any framework. I will attach an image to show that.

Comment: Yes- but still, in no way it can guess variables and types that are concealed inside strings inside your source code.

Comment: You could likewise be reading your type data from a text file, creating them by comosing the strings randomcally. Can you see that it is just _unfeasible_, but for actually instantiating your code, and using statistic methods to check which data types can work as each parameter in each of the callables in your code? (which is, just to say, unfeasible as wel)

Answer (score 1):

You can use stub file described in [PEP 561](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0561/). Then is stub files you can addsignature of automaticaly created files.

if `pyi` file You add entry

```
class MyTest: 
    def __init__(a: int): ...
```

Then you will have type hinting in PyCharm.

But I do not know how to add hint for only part of entries from file. I ask for it here: [Partial stub in PyCharm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55160797/partial-stub-in-pycharm)

Answer (score 0):

That's a weird way to `make_init()`. Why not just graft a real function? I suppose PyCharm can potentially see through `setattr`, but I bet it can't see through `eval`.

E.g.

```
def make_init():
  def my_init(self, a:int = 1):  # Should be noted by IDE.
    pass
  return my_init
```

Comment: My point is the dynamic and custom. Just like to be an ORM which is using the `exec` to make sure the dynamic and custom init function. And the PyCharm can hint it.

Comment: Do you mean that you need to syntheize the function so unpredictable that the only way that would work is `eval`? I frankly suppose that the lack of type inference in PyCharm may be the least of the troubles of such an approach. At the very-very least, you can use a function defined in source code as shown, with an annotate signature that the IDE can understand, and _call_ your eval-produced function from it.