# Type hint a specific module in PyCharm

Tags: python, pycharm, type-hinting

Consider the following code:

[image]

PyCharm automatically senses that this is a module that could refer to one or more backing libraries.

Is it possible to specify this manually for other module variables as well? Something like the following:

```
from pyqtgraph.Qt import QtWidgets
QtWidgets: Union[PyQt5.QtWidgets.pyi, PySide2.QtWidgets.pyi] # <-- I want to add this type hint
```

Behind the scenes, `pyqtgraph` is dynamically constructing dummy `QtWidgets` to point to one of several libraries at runtime, but PyCharm doesn't know this. Is there a way for me to manually add that type hint (`QtWidgets.pyi`) to a module that I import (In this case, `pyqtgraph.Qt.QtWidgets`)?

I posted [here](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/4403079694354-How-to-type-hint-a-union-of-static-modules-) as well, for reference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

As you can see here, it doesn't show me hints for `sys.Test`, as it doesn't exist.
What you can do - you can use Stubs, aka .pyi files.
i just added a `sys.pyi` file, [it must be named the same as your module, `pyqtgraph.pyi` in your case].
it doesn't evaluate the file but uses it to gather type hintings.
the result is
[image]

And the content of `sys.pyi` is:

```py
Test: bytes
```

You can read about stubs, Here: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/stubs.html

Comment: This works, thanks! I combined it with https://stackoverflow.com/a/63552927/9463643  to avoid stubbing the entire library, so I just added your pyi solution to the dynamic module.

Comment: Edit: The linked SO post doesn't actually provide intellisense for the remaining methods -- it just keeps PyCharm from raising errors... Looks like stubs have to be defined nowhere or everywhere, then... Following https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-46104

Comment: Stubs are just being used for type hinting, they don't get executed anywhere.

Comment: Right -- but currently in PyCharm if you add stubs for a single submodule, PyCharm expects you to provide stubs for everything else otherwise it breaks all remaining code completion

Comment: WOW, i didn't know that, mine works perfectly as it searches for .pyi files, and if it doesn't find any for a particular module that it just uses the normal .py files to gather the type hinting from. anyway thanks for acknowledging!